# Обобщающие слова при однородных членах и двоеточие

Tags: двоеточие

Помогите, пожалуйста! Как объяснить пятиклассникам разницу в двух предложениях?

Транспорт бывает наземный, водный и воздушный.

В Пушкинском заповеднике три огромных парка: Тригорский, Петровский и Михайловский.

В первом предложении нет обобщающего слова, потому что (что?) транспорт — подлежащее, наземный, водный, воздушный (какой?) — сказуемое. Разные члены предложения, значит, здесь нет обобщающего слова и двоеточия.

Но во втором предложении двоеточие ставится, хотя (что?) три парка — подлежащее, а Тригорский, Петровский и Михайловский (какие?) — определения.

Подробнее: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/question/obobschayuschie-slova-pri-odnorodnyh-chlenah

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, нужно начать с объяснения значения "обобщающее слово" - оно должно обобщать значения других однородных членов. Обобщающие слова называют более общее, родовое, понятие при более узких, видовых.

Например, *смородина, малина, черника* – это **ягоды**. «Ягоды» – более широкое понятие по отношению к «смородине, малине, чернике» и может стать поэтому обобщающим словом.

В степи, за рекой, по дорогам — **везде** было пусто (Л. Толстой);
В корзине была **дичь**: два тетерева и утка (И. Гончаров). https://3dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/1583568

Примеры для 5 класса сложные, они ведь не учили составные именные сказуемые, неполные предложения, словосочетание в роли одного члена предложения.

В  предложении *Транспорт бывает наземный, водный и воздушный* нет обобщающего слова, потому что нет однородного члена с общим значением, например, **разный**. Слово транспорт к однородным членам не относится, это подлежащее, оно не отвечает на вопрос какой?, как остальные однородные сказуемые: наземный, водный, воздушный (какой?) .

Во втором предложении *В Пушкинском заповеднике три огромных парка: Тригорский, Петровский и Михайловский* двоеточие ставится, потому что **три парка** — обобщающее подлежащее, а Тригорский, Петровский и Михайловский (какие парки?) — не определения, а тоже подлежащие с пропущенными одинаковыми частями: В Пушкинском заповеднике три огромных парка: Тригорский парк, Петровский парк и Михайловский парк. В первой части предложения пропущено сказуемое (есть, находятся), подлежащее выражено количественным сочетанием **три парка**, а во второй части перечислены, какие именно три парка есть в заповеднике.

Так что это как раз обобщающий член предложения.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно сложные примеры, хотя взяты из книги для 5 класса. Подлежащее, выраженное словосочетанием, проходили уже. Попробую объяснить! Главное, что сама поняла.

Comment: Чтобы подчеркнуть перечисляемость, можно поставить двоеточие и в первом примере: *Транспорт бывает: наземный, водный и воздушный.* Тогда там делается соответствующая пауза. Можно ведь?